# Customizing ISO 19139 metadata profile in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml, metadata, iso-19115, iso-19139

I'm using the ISO 19115/19139 metadata standard, and I need to convert some **optional** elements into **mandatory** elements. Is it possible to achieve this using ArcCatalog as the metadata editor?

[About metadata standards and profiles](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Metadata_styles_and_standards/003t00000008000000/) says "*A profile may further restrict the optionality of a metadata element, making it mandatory where before it was optional.*"

In ArcCatalog I can set ISO 19139 as the metadata standard:

[image]

but how can I edit my instance of ISO 19139 (to make a custom profile) so that (for example) *lineage* is mandatory instead of optional?

[image]

Under *ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\Metadata\Translator\Rules* there is a file *ISO19139_min_schema.txt*.

Can I edit this file, and if so what is the syntax for making *lineage* mandatory?

Comment: I believe that behind the scenes the Metadata standards are XML stylesheets (or something similar) - these might be editable with XML tags to say mandatory.

Comment: @Midavalo that sounds about right. The big question is, where are the files located, and what is the syntax for making something mandatory? _Metadata\Stylesheets\ArcGIS_Imports\ISO19139.xslt_ doesn't seem to list this, and I'm unsure how to edit the aforementioned _ISO19139_min_schema.txt_ file

Comment: I found a folder with `.cfg` files but these don't appear to have a flag for mandatory or optional either.

Comment: @Midavalo I think the *min_schema.txt* file looks most promising as "this schema contains the rules for presence of the minimum mandatory and conditional elements". But I haven't figured out the syntax yet for adding Lineage as a mandatory element

Comment: I think it unlikely to be something in an XSL stylesheet that would enforce this restriction, I would look for a DTD or XML schema (or schematron)

Comment: There's an easy 100 pts bounty going begging for a quick summary of where this question of yours currently stands, as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The length of time that this ArcGIS Desktop question has remained unanswered suggests to me that it may only be possible using functionality in or targeted for ArcGIS Pro.

I notice that Mid-term aims of the [ArcGIS Pro Roadmap](https://geonet.esri.com/community/gis/applications/arcgis-pro/blog/2017/07/10/arcgis-pro-roadmap) includes:

> Metadata Enhancements – Support majority of metadata functionality

To ensure that what you seek makes it into ArcGIS Pro, if not into the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture, I recommend posting an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) and linking to it here so that it may attract the necessary support.

Comment: Thanks for  the tip. The urgency for this request has passed, so I don't think I'll bother with the ArcGIS Ideas page. I've wasted far too much time there in the past ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use ArcGIS Metadata toolkit
https://support.esri.com/en/download/7511

It documents how to create and share custom metadata styles based on the ArcGIS metadata editor provided with ArcGIS for Desktop in the ArcMap, ArcCatalog, and ArcGlobe applications.
Customizations that change how you view and export metadata, validate metadata using an XML schema, and reduce the number of pages available in the ArcGIS metadata editor require no programming.

download this and unzip it and there you will find a pdf "ArcGIS 10.5.x Metadata Toolkit"

Inside that pdf see the section "Creating a custom metadata XSLT stylesheet for display" and "Customizing the validation rules for a page"

There you can have the option to change the way how ArcGIS metadata editor treats a standard and you can